# WordPress: How to get all tags used in all posts in some category?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have category like `Technology` and I want get all posts from this `category`. And then I need to select all `tags` used on that posts and order them by count of usage. But I want to count usage from posts which are in `Technology` category.

Is this possible to do without accessing directly to database?

Comment: you have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787341/get-all-tags-based-on-specific-category-including-all-tags-from-child-categorie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) as it's basically dealing with taxonomies ( tags ) .